# Xcode ActionSheetPicker linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, actionsheetpicker

I am trying to add ActionSheetPicker manually to my project. And when add the folder I get `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` error. After removing the ActionSheetPicker folders, my projects builds just fine. Help please. (I am using Xcode 8.1)

Comment: Can u share which action sheet exactly you are trying to use ?

Comment: I have only added the folder to the project and there are lots of files. I haven't imported any file to my project yet.

Comment: Is it a third party library ? Can u provide link to the library.
I just want to know which is the library, from where you have downloaded the library any link.
Also you are using Swift 3.0, I just want to confirm if you are using the correct version of the library or not.

Comment: https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 here. I am not using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Somehow I had added it twice to my project. Removing one reference did it for me.